# RabbitMQ + MQTT: unable to publish any messages: login timeout

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, mqtt

I deployed a RabbitMQ server with an MQTT plugin. All of a sudden, my app was no able to publish any messages:

```
info: paho: MQTT Client using: ssl://example.com:8883/
error: paho: [net]      connect got error EOF
error: paho: [net]      connect got error EOF
error: paho: [client]   Failed to connect to a broker
```

Same thing happens when I try to publish a message using CLI: it times out in exactly 10 seconds:

```
$ mosquitto_pub -h example.com -u "user" -P "pass" -t "test" -m "123"
Error: The connection was lost.
```

I checked the server logs, and they only have this:

```
[error] closing MQTT connection "1.2.3.4:40462 -> 4.5.6.7:1883" (login timeout)
```

"Login timeout". Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how RabbitMQ+MQTT behave when you're out of disk space: it just starts dropping connections, and the only message you get in the logs is this:

> closing MQTT connection: (login timeout)

Get some disk space, reboot (just in case), and it will work just fine.

Read more about this: [Free Disk Space Alarms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/disk-alarms.html)